# Why does this ducted fan have 10 blades (instead of some odd number of blades)?

Tags: air, fan

I've searched online and learnt that odd number of blades reduce turbulence and noise. I counted my home's ceiling fan, it has 3 blades, then I counted my laptop's fan, 13 blades! Amazing!

But later, I came across [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor#/media/File:2-coil_10-blade_DC_brushless_motor.jpg) on Wikipedia:ducted fan, it has unusual 10 blades. I'm confused, does all ducted fans have even number of blades? Why?

Thank you!

Comment: My intuitive thought would be that not all manufacturers take this into account, and the picture on Wikipedia just happens to show a "turbulent" fan. E.g. Noctua fans, which are famous for being quiet in the PC building community, all seem to have an odd number of fan blades, from what I can tell from the first page of Google images.

Comment: this might be relevant http://mstudioblackboard.tudelft.nl/duwind/Wind%20energy%20online%20reader/Static_pages/blades_number.htm

Comment: I've  never seen a simple explanation of why some devices use an even number of fans and some odd.  I think the details of each design are the usual balance of efficiency and cost as well as specific issues related to specific designs.  I've seen plenty of 4 bladed propellers on aircraft and boats.

Comment: Just as a guess,it would be more difficult to set up a resonance when the number is odd, even numbers will be symmetrically placed.about the axis, so  it would depend how stable the casing is, whether it would make a difference in noise between odd and even blades.